# Rounding numbers on specific values of digits

Tags: r, rounding

I want to round a certain decimal date either down to the present year or up to the next year, depending on if the decimals are smaller or larger then xxxx.75 (october). it is for adding historical food prices to a time series.

```
table(Marriages$stop)

1721.09863013699 1728.53825136612 1728.66120218579 1730.13698630137  1730.3698630137  1730.6301369863 1732.15573770492 
               2                2                2                2                2                2                2 
1732.56830601093 1733.10410958904 1736.40163934426 1736.63114754098  1736.7650273224 1740.10109289617 1740.41530054645 
               2                2                2                2                2                2                2 
1741.54794520548  1742.2904109589 1742.66849315068 1742.74520547945 1742.82191780822 1743.14520547945 1743.81643835616 
               2                2                2                2                2                2                2
```

This is how I tried so far:

```
Marriages$year <- ifelse(Marriages$tstop...), round(Marriages$tstop - 1, digits = 0), round(Marriages$tstop, digits = 0))
```

I am missing a statement in the first part of the if clause. how can I find the first and second digit of my stop-year and round it accordingly?

Comment: Add `0.25` to every date and truncate ?

Comment: hehe, could work. I´ll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the decimals by simply subtracting the floored number from itself, check if it is greater than 0.75 and round up or down accordingly.

For a vector:

```
x <- c(1721.09863013699, 1728.53825136612, 1728.66120218579,
       1730.13698630137,  1730.3698630137,  1730.6301369863,
       1732.15573770492, 1732.56830601093, 1733.10410958904,
       1736.40163934426, 1736.63114754098, 1736.7650273224,
       1740.10109289617, 1740.41530054645, 1741.54794520548,
       1742.2904109589, 1742.66849315068, 1742.74520547945,
       1742.82191780822, 1743.14520547945, 1743.81643835616)


ifelse(x - floor(x) >= 0.75, ceiling(x), floor(x))
```

returns:

```
[1] 1721 1728 1728 1730 1730 1730 1732 1732 1733 1736 1736 1737 1740
[14] 1740 1741 1742 1742 1742 1743 1743 1744
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Your data

```
  test<-c(1721.09863013699,1728.53825136612,1736.765027322)
```

Your output

```
  to_round_up<-test-trunc(test,0)>0.75
  test[to_round_up]<-test[to_round_up]+1
  trunc(test,0)
[1] 1721 1728 1737
```

Comment: this one works best for me as it is more how I would write it. personal taste, nothing more...: Marriages$year <- ifelse(Marriages$tstop - floor(Marriages$tstop) >= 0.75, ceiling(Marriages$tstop), floor(Marriages$tstop))